# New software can't be installed error

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I have just installed Ubuntu a few days ago and really liked it. But I have a serious problem which I can't fix. When I try to install something from Ubuntu Software Center I got an error like this:

> New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair now?

And when I hit repair I got another error like this:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 244252 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to install `kde-config-telepathy-accounts`, but this packages contains the file `/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service`.

That file however is also part of the preinstalled package `account-plugin-google` and does therefore already exist. The package manager does refuse to overwrite already existing files by default, that's why you get the error.

**You have three options:**

1. Do not install `kde-config-telepathy-accounts` and purge the partially installed files as well as the packages depending on it again using these terminal commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-telepathy-minimal kde-telepathy
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. If you don't need that Google account integration (also needed for `unity-scope-gdrive` and maybe more), you could uninstall it.

   That can be done using this terminal command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge account-plugin-google
   ```

   You will have to finish the installation of the other package though, like this:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kde-config-telepathy-accounts
   ```
3. You can also ignore the warning and let `kde-config-telepathy-accounts` overwrite that file with its own version.

   ```
   sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install kde-config-telepathy-accounts
   ```

   *There's no guarantee though that after overwriting this file with a different version, the original package `accounts-plugin-google` is still compatible with it and will not crash or work in an unintended way! Proceed with care!*

Comment: I tried first two options but none of them worked.  First one gave an error like this: "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)." and second one gave an error like this: "E: Unable to locate package accounts-plugin"

Comment: @KaanTürkmen Sorry, there was a mistake in the command of option 2, I gave you the wrong package name. I fixed that now. About option 1, please give me a moment to spin up a VM and test it...

Comment: Still getting error unable to locate package in the second option :(

Comment: @KaanTürkmen Okay, it was my fault, I mistyped it again. This time it's definitely correct. I also updated the command for option 1, but on your system there might possibly be more dependency packages that need to be removed at the same time. Tell me the exact error message if it still does not work, but I think it should be fine now.

Comment: No error message, and yet I don't have any problem with software center. Looks like method 1 worked. Thank you sooo much.